# Cloudwatch mon-put-instance-data not reporting on AMI-cloned instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

After cloning an EC2 instance using AMI (to change a hosts security group), none of the statistics reported by the Amazon-provided mon-put-instance-data.pl script are showing up in CloudWatch.

I can confirm that the script is reporting the data to CloudWatch but it's not showing up in the CloudWatch console:

```
# ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --aws-credential-file=/root/.aws-credentials --mem-util --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ --swap-util
Successfully reported metrics to CloudWatch. Reference Id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-93f25b4efbc7
```

Comment: Figured it out thanks to strace.  The current instance id is cached in /var/tmp/aws-mon and that incorrect cache was preserved via the AMI process.

The solution:
    # mv /var/tmp/aws-mon /var/tmp/aws-mon.bak

Answer (score 25):

Figured it out thanks to strace.  The current instance id is cached in /var/tmp/aws-mon and that incorrect cache was preserved via the AMI process.

The solution:

```
# mv /var/tmp/aws-mon /var/tmp/aws-mon.bak
```

Comment: I believe a better solution would be to remove the temporary folder when the new instance is created: "rm -rf /var/tmp/aws-mon"

Comment: I'm see a similar thing with a Windows instance. The CloudWatch Agent seems to be using a cached instance id, every new instance writes to the same stream. Not sure what to delete from the AMI for Windows?